# How to instantiate an object of an Activity Class from non-Activity Class?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am creating a java class  that DOES NOT extends Activity, and in its constructor, I want to instantiate an object from another class that instantiate `SQLiteOpenHelper`. The  problem is, when instantiating an object of the `SQLiteOpenHelper`class I need to pass a `Context` of the current class that DOES NOT extend Activity. What argument should I pass to an instance of the `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Constructor of SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
public class MPLDataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MPL.db";
private static final String MPL_TABLE_NAME = "MPLData";

public MPLDataBase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}
```

Class that instantiate SQLiteOpenHelper: ***This is a NON_ACTIVITY Class***

```
public class NotifyArrayAdapter {

private MPLDataBase mplOpenHelperDB = null;
private SQLiteDatabase sqliteDB = null;
private int itemClickedPos;

public NotifyArrayAdapter() {
    mplOpenHelperDB = new MPLDataBase(WHAT_SHOULD_I_PASS_HERE);
}
```

***NotifyArrayAdapterClass***

```
public class NotifyArrayAdapter {

private MPLDataBase mplOpenHelperDB = null;
private SQLiteDatabase sqliteDB = null;
private int itemClickedPos;

public NotifyArrayAdapter(Context context) {
    if (this.mplOpenHelperDB == null) {
        this.mplOpenHelperDB = new MPLDataBase(context);
    }
    if (this.sqliteDB == null) {
        this.sqliteDB = mplOpenHelperDB.getWritableDatabase();
    }

}
public void deleteAtPos(int pos) {
    if(! this.sqliteDB.isOpen()) {
        this.sqliteDB = mplOpenHelperDB.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    this.itemClickedPos = pos;
    int [] dbIDs = this.mplOpenHelperDB.getIDs();
    mplOpenHelperDB.deleteRow(dbIDs[this.itemClickedPos]);
}

public void deleteAllDBRows() {
    if(! this.sqliteDB.isOpen()) {
        this.sqliteDB = mplOpenHelperDB.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    mplOpenHelperDB.deleteALLRows();
}
```

}

Comment: Will you call this class in any Activity?

Comment: Where are you using your `NotifyArrayAdapter`? `Context`s are not specific to classes. You can pass them along. Just like the way you do when initializing dialogs, system services, ...

Comment: @SuperSuer yes the class `NotifyArrayAdapter` i am creating it so later i will instantiating it from inside another class that extends activity

Comment: @MiroMarkarian I hope my reply to super_suer answers your inquiry

Comment: can you please paste that code where you call this class

Comment: @Elpharaoh Yes. Then you can pass the context from there!

Comment: Try passing the getActivity().getApplicationContext() around;

Comment: @SuperSuer which class do you mean? sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: @SuperSuer please see the update, i posted the class as you requested

Comment: @Elpharaoh Sorry, but I was asking for the class that extends the Activity, where you are calling the _NotifyArrayAdapter_, again sorry if I miss led you!

Comment: @SuperSuer no problem i appreciate you attemept to help. but that calss is very long one, but what matters it, it is extends activity

Comment: @Elpharaoh OK paste that code of class [Here in PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/) and give me link to that, I'll tacke a look at that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass current `context` to your `MPLDataBase` constructor

```
 public NotifyArrayAdapter(Context con) {
  mplOpenHelperDB = new MPLDataBase(con);
 }
```

like if you call this from any `Activity` then

```
 NotifyArrayAdapter notifyarrayAdapter = new NotifyArrayAdapter(yourActivity.This);
```

like if you call this from any `Fargment` then

```
 NotifyArrayAdapter notifyarrayAdapter = new NotifyArrayAdapter(getActivity());
```